# Change Oracle user home directory at OS level after Oracle Databse/Client Software Installation

Tags: oracle, linux, installation

Can we change oracle user's home directory at OS level after Oracle Database/Client Software-Only installation?

- No database has been created yet.
- We want to change the home directory to `/Oracle/profile/oracle` from `/home/oracle`.

Comment: Deinstall + install. It takes like 10 minutes.

Comment: On a second thought, if you meant the the home directory of oracle user at OS level, you can do that without any problem.

Comment: @Balazs ~ Yes, I meant the home directory of oracle user at OS level!

Comment: Just make sure you keep clear in your own mind the difference between 1) the OS home directory of the user 'oracle' and 2) the ORACLE_HOME, which is where the oracle software resides.  Oracle doesn't give a flip about #1, so that becomes an OS question rather than an Oracle question.  And keep that distinction in mind when evaluating the other responses . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment:

> Yes, I meant the home directory of oracle user at OS level!

You can easily achieve that.

We have a user called `ora`

```
[root@myserver /]# su - ora
[ora@myserver ~]$ pwd
/home/ora
```

And it has its home directory as `/home/ora`.
Let's create another home directory for the user `ora`.

```
[root@myserver ora]# mkdir -p /home/profile
```

Let's move the files such as `.bash_profile` and directories like `Desktop` and `Documents`, from the old home directory to new one.

```
[root@myserver ora]# cp -a /home/ora /home/profile/
```

Finally, modify the user to change the home directory. Make sure that there are no active sessions exist for the user.

```
[root@myserver ora]# usermod -d /home/profile/ora/ ora
```

Let's check the result.

```
[root@myserver ora]# su - ora
[ora@myserver ~]$ pwd
/home/profile/ora/
```

Answer (score -2):

To change the Oracle Home variable in your current install you can use the command:

for Linux/Unix:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/Oracle/profile/oracle
```

for Windows:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=c:\Oracle\profile\oracle
```

In Windows, remember you will have to edit registry keys as well: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOMEID
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ALL_HOMES
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services.